# Is there any Diagramm tool for Tablets with drawing recognition?

Tags: visio, tablet, diagramming, uml

Is there any Diagram tool for Tablets with drawing recognition ?
Perfect for me would be
- a tablet
- visio support
- handwriting recognition

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Smart Diagram for Android answers your query, although I haven't tried it... Will try and update.

Edit: it's a brilliant tool on my rooted nook color, so it answers your needs...

Links:
[image: QR code]

[normal](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sillycube.android.DiagramMaker.core&feature=search_result)

[pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sillycube.android.DiagramMaker.corepro&feature=search_result)

Comment: That is right. It don´t fits my means 100% but its a good start.